# Laravel eager loading with eloquent-sluggable package

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, eloquent

I am having an issue getting eager loading to work, when using the eloquent-sluggable package.

Have a class Page, which has a relationship to a class MenuItem

I need to load the page along with the related menuitem on every page load, however when using the With() method

```
$page = Page::with('menuItems')->findBySlugOrId($id);
```

I get the error

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1992:Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::findBySlugOrId()"
```

Is there no way to use the sluggable interface with the With method? Or is there a better way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no findBySlugOrId method as the error says, findBySlug is a method that actually compare the slug_field wuth the give value. You can do this
Post::with('relation')->whereId($value)->findBySlug($value); in that order because findBySlug return first record, thats mean a single object and you cant apply where on single objects.